# Magento 2: Delete images of deleted products

Tags: magento2, product-images, media-images

I wanna know how delete the images + cache images from deleted products. 
I tried: 
https://magecomp.com/magento-2-image-clean.html
https://github.com/hungersoft/magento2-image-clean
https://github.com/sivaschenko/magento2-clean-media

And no solution, they doesn't delete the images

Any suggestion? 
I used it in the 1.9.X but the code doesn't work.

https://www.devproblems.com/magento-remove-images-of-deleted-products/

Alfredo

Comment: How do you know the images haven't been deleted and how many do you think there are?